# Multimeter misuse by shorting a 220 voltage through it

Tags: multimeter, damage

I intended to measure an AC voltage, but I forgot the multimeter on the resistance position (200 Ohm scale). I've shorted the 220V through the multimeter.

The fuse is not damaged, neither the bridge, but it is not working anymore for AC voltage, it gives wrong measurements for DC voltage, and the resistance scale seems to function only on the highest position on the scale.

Can I throw away the thing?

Answer (score 6):

Yup, sounds like it's toast.  You *can* throw the thing away at any time, but it sounds like in this case that's about the only thing left to do if you don't want to salvage parts from it.

Fancy expensive meters might protect themselves from something like this, but 220 VAC in Ohms mode is really major abuse.  I can see cheap meters not bothering with protection for this kind of event.  The easiest form of protection if one were to be added would probably be a crowbar so the fuse pops.

Comment: [This answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5509/2110) confirms that expensive meters _are_ better protected in exactly this case.

Comment: Best trick of all is to set meter dial correctly BUT to leave positive lead plugged into 20A DC range and THEN (try to) measure mains voltage. Ask me how I know :-). Something one tends to only do once.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I "tried" that once, the probe tip melted but no other problems (I can't recall if the circuit breaker tripped, that was a long time ago)

Comment: Yep, measuring the current of a stiff voltage source while plugged for high current is a good one, did that with a 48V telecoms battery array, I was seeing the arc for the next day. For this sort of thing the better class of meter has HRC fuses built into the probes, it is the place where a real CAT III or IV instrument shows its value (It may fail, but unlike the cheap stuff will not explode).

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar "100+V @ 200 ohm" experience recently, with a cheap chinese meter. I opened it up, had a look inside and measured the SMD resistors - there weren't that many of them. A 900 ohm one was blown open. After replacing it, the meter seems to work fine.

It's worth giving it a try, before trashing it.

Comment: I'm quite happy with it, actually - it's kind of a relief to blow-up a 5$ meter instead of a 50$ one :)

Comment: Nothing like a buying a new multimeter to fix the old one :P HAHA

Comment: @Shungun having a spare of any important tool is beneficial even if you never need to make multiple simultaneous measurements.

Answer (score 0):

if your multimeter is digital then try replacing and troubleshooting for
linear comparator  IC's.

> > if your Multimeter is Single Chip then ya throw it away.

sorry about this, I don't think any multimeter is a single chip.

If you really want to dig into this, then download the circuit diagram of your
multimeter, invoke the test cases, and try to troubleshoot it. You just simply
do ad-hoc troubleshooting on this, you don't simply need to concern about 
delta debugging like things.Because it's a simple circuit.

it's easy to throw it away.

Comment: Who makes single chip multimeter?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing a circuit diagram coming with a multimeter.

Comment: I think I'm wrong on Single Chip meter.But my meter got a circuit diagram of it in it's manual.